# Barycentric subdivision of regular CW decomposition is a combinatorial manifold?

Tags: manifolds, triangulation, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

Suppose $X$ is a PL manifold (with boundary) and let $(X,X_{i})$ be a regular CW complex. Is the barycentric subdivision of $(X,X_{i})$ a combinatorial manifold? *Answer given in comments.*

**Definition:** A combinatorial manifold is a triangulation of a $n$-manifold such that the link of every vertex $v$ is a $(n-\dim(v)-1)$-sphere.

Comment: Any non-combinatorial triangulation of a PL manifold should be a counterexample.

Comment: They don't exist. Just been doing some research and Corollary 1.6.2 in "Topological embeddings" says that every triangulation of a PL manifold is combinatorial. So I suppose this is the answer too.

Comment: No, that's not true - you want further conditions. One of the standard examples is to take a homology sphere $M$, triangulate it, and suspend it twice. The double suspension theorem says that the resulting manifold is homeomorphic to a sphere, so doubly suspending the triangulation gives a triangulation of a sphere, but such that the link of two of the vertices is $\Sigma M$, which is not even a manifold.

Comment: Could you explain the disparity between your example and http://tinyurl.com/nmz9bdp? (Scroll down to Corollary 1.6.2)

Comment: It seems subtle, and I don't have the time to figure it out, but it's certainly not true. I think the author is assuming the triangulation "plays nicely" with the PL structure somehow.

Comment: BTW: the answer to Q1.6.1 is now known to be no in dimension 4, due to work of Donaldson (because smooth is equivalent to PL in this dimension); 1.6.2. is known to be false in dimension 4 by work of Casson and in higher dimensions by (very recent; it's from 2013) work of Manolescu; 1.6.3 should be true by the existence of triangulable non-PL manifolds (which at the very least Galewski and Stern showed; I don't know if this was done earlier). 1.6.5 is true in dim 4 by Freedman's work.

Comment: Thank you, this was very interesting. Is there any distinguished class of manifolds with the property that all triangulations are combinatorial? I remember reading that this holds for all manifolds below 4?

Comment: It's certainly true for 3-manifolds. I think it's true for 4-manifolds but would hesitate to say so in absolute terms. For 5 and up, you can always construct a non-combinatorial triangulation as above on the sphere and then connected sum your manifold with it to get a non-combinatorial triangulation of your manifold.

Comment: "For 5 and up, you can always construct a non-combinatorial triangulation as above on the sphere and then connected sum your manifold with it to get a non-combinatorial triangulation of your manifold." Very clever.